# Linear interpolation in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to learn some techniques in excel and I have values like these:

```
86.49
86.5
86.51
86.52
-
-
-
-
-
-
86.65
```

The values are increasing. I want to use linear interpolation in order to predict values from 86.52 until 86.65. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Dr. Genius, try Googling [linear+interpolation+using+excel+formula](https://www.google.com/search?q=linear+interpolation+using+excel+formula) Top 2 results: ``1`` [indeed: How To Perform Linear Interpolation in Microsoft Excel](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-interpolate-in-excel) and ``2`` [Engineerexcel: Linear Interpolation in Excel](https://engineerexcel.com/linear-interpolation-in-excel/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you `FORECAST` and `FORECAST.LINEAR` functions.
[See Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forecast-and-forecast-linear-functions-50ca49c9-7b40-4892-94e4-7ad38bbeda99)